# ¿Se pueden utilizar los dos puntos dentro de una pregunta?

Tags: gramática

Se que los dos puntos pueden posponerse a los signos de interrogación, pero tengo la duda de si dentro de una pregunta pueden ponerse dos puntos.

Actualmente no tengo ningún ejemplo, pero luciría algo así:
¿texto........: texto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque es raro encontrar dos puntos dentro de una pregunta, no hay ninguna razón por la que debiera considerarse incorrecto su uso, por ejemplo:

- ¿Quién dijo: "Síganme, que no los voy a defraudar"?

El motivo por el cual es raro es que solo podrían aparecer citas cortas, como la precedente, a fin de permitir la entonación interrogativa de principio a fin, mientras que sería casi -- si no totalmente -- imposible encontrar en oraciones interrogativas otros usos de los dos puntos, como cuando se emplean para introducir ejemplos, enumeraciones o inferencias.

Comment: ¿Quizá "¿qué te gusta más: el campo o la ciudad?" se podría escribir con dos puntos introduciendo una enumeración? ¿O sería con coma? La verdad es que no he encontrado ninguna fuente oficial al respecto.